# Eliminate 0 in a set function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to eliminate 0 from a set function

```
uniq_events = set((row[self.param]) for row in self.fpt)
o/p
set(['1','2','0','3')
```

Now i want an o/p like this

```
set(['1','2','3')
```

Comment: I want to eliminate only if uniq_events consists of None or 0 in the set.

Comment: `uniq_events = set((row[self.param]) for row in self.fpt) - {'0'}`

Answer (score 2):

> I want to eliminate only if uniq_events consists of `None` or `0` in the set.

You could use `evt -= {'0', None}`:

```
In [10]: evt = set(['1','2','0','3',None])

In [11]: evt
Out[11]: set(['1', '0', '3', '2', None])

In [12]: evt -= {'0', None}

In [13]: evt
Out[13]: set(['1', '3', '2'])
```

Alternatively, you can get rid of the unwanted elements while populating the set:

```
uniq_events = set(row[self.param] for row in self.fpt if row not in [None, '0'])
```

Comment: why you make additional action?you could add two conditions in the population loop.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry: I am not seeing a loop, so not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in-place:

```
uniq_events.discard("0")
```

or create a new set:

```
new_events = uniq_events - {"0"}
```

Comment: uniq_events = set((row[self.Header1]) 
for row in self.filepointer) new_events = uniq_events - {0}
     return new_events

Comment: The problem is that the OP has a `set` of strings, not numbers. Do `uniq_events.discard('0')` or `new_events = uniq_events - {'0'}`.

Comment: Updated the answer to use strings